# Syncing checkboxes between buddypress and mailchimp using autochimp

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, mailchimp, buddypress, autochimp

When signing up for my BuddyPress website a user gets the option to register for 3 separate newsletters through 3 checkboxes. They are saved into their custom profile fields.

I tried to sync those with MailChimp, using AutoChimp, but I can't add a checkbox field to my List (List --> Settings --> List fields and *|MERGE|* tags).

I tried syncing it to a text field, but that didn't work.

Anybody got an idea how to sync that information?

Comment: I have the same question. May I ask have you found the answer?